# using mod_disk_cache is it possible to cache only the static contents of a page containing both static and dynamic content?

Tags: caching, outputcache, http-caching

I am trying to implement MOD_DISK_CACHE. Is it possible to cache only the static contents of a page containing both static and dynamic content?

i.e, if I want to cache the homepage of a user profile, I just want to cache the static contents of that page which will be common/generic to all the users, while the dynamic contents for eg `"Welcome <Username>!!!"`, which is different for different users should be handled separately.

Any pointers would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect `mod_disk_cache` to operate on dynamic content (e.g. PHP) at all. That isn't disk content you're caching. Dynamic content is generated outside of Apache (in the case of PHP, by the PHP interpreter).

To have HTTP caching for these pages, you need to have something like Varnish (a real HTTP cache) that sits between the visitor and the server. It caches all content for you, including dynamic content. With the proper `Expires`, `Vary` and `Cache-Control` headers you can avoid getting certain pages to get cached (e.g admin pages).

Varnish also supports special "edge side include" like tags; `<esi:include>`. These still allow you to have dynamic parts in your cached page.